Using FoldList on multilevel list
Given
t7 = {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 11}, {7, 2}, {11, 9}, {13, 19},{9,17}}

Elements should be selected such as the second part is in ascending order. which gives
{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}

I can do it by
t8 = Union@FoldList[Max, 0, t7[[All, 2]]]
Rest[Table[SelectFirst[t7, #[[2]] == t8[[i]] &], {i, Length[t8]}]]

But I'd like to learn more elegant ways to do that by using FoldList (or Function or others).

Why {{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}} and not {{3,1}, {7,2}, {11,9}, {9,17}} ?

Using NestWhileList and Pick:
NestWhileList[
  Drop[#, Pick[Range@Length@#, Sign[#[[All, 2]] - #[[1, 2]] - .5], 
       1][[1]] - 1] &, t7, Max@#[[All, 2]] > #[[1, 2]] &][[All, 1]]


{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}

Using FixedPoint and Delete:
FixedPoint[
 Delete[#, Position[Sign@Differences@#[[All, 2]], -1] + 1] &, t7]


{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}

Using FixedPoint and Pick:
FixedPoint[Pick[#, Prepend[Sign@Differences@#[[All, 2]], 1], 1] &, t7]


{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}

Using FixedPoint and Part:
FixedPoint[#[[Pick[Range@Length@#, 
     Prepend[Sign@Differences@#[[All, 2]], 1], 1]]] &, t7]


{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}


Update
@lericr has suggested this point-free version
DeleteDuplicates[t7, Map[Last]@*Greater]

(* {{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}} *) 

Original Answer
DeleteDuplicates[t7, Greater[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &]

(* {{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}} *)

t7two = {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 11}, {7, 2}, {11, 9}, {13, 19}, {9, 17}}

DeleteDuplicates[t7two, Greater[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &]

    (* {{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}} *)


I love this one! Point-free version: DeleteDuplicates[t7, Map[Last]@*Greater] .

What function would you use if there were no Duplicates?

@user57467.  I think I would use the same (or a very similar function).  For example, DeleteDuplicates[Join[Range[10], Range[20, 11, -1]], Greater] gives {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20}.

t = {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 11}, {7, 2}, {11, 9}, {13, 19}, {9, 17}};

Using Fold:
Fold[If[#2[[-1]] > #[[-1, 2]], Append[#, #2], #] &, {First[t]}, Rest[t]]


{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}


This is the fastest (9x > than DeleteDuplicates, 2x > Select for example).

Using only ReplaceRepeated on pattern matching:
t7 //. {m___, elem:{_, y1_}, {_, y2_}, r___} /; y1>y2 :> {m, elem, r}

With a simple ReplaceAll, this FixedPoint version mimiks the ReplaceRepeated functionality above:
FixedPoint[# /. {m___, elem:{_, y1_}, {_, y2_}, r___} /; y1 > y2 :> {m, elem, r} &, t7]

EDIT
In case of a non-decreasing sequence, the above answers are correct. For a (strictly) ascending variant, one has to use >= instead of >.
EDIT2
Unnecessary pattern naming deleted.

EDIT
t7 = {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 11}, {7, 2}, {11, 9}, {13, 19}, {9, 17}};
t6 = {{{13, 41}, 12}, {{17, 53}, 24}, {{31, 97}, 25}, {{53, 167}, 9}};

pickAscending[k_List, fn_] := Module[
  {temp = -\[Infinity]},
  First@Last@Reap@Do[
      If[fn@k[[i]] > temp
        , {Sow[k[[i]]]; temp = fn@k[[i]]}
        , Sow[Style[x, Red]]
        ];
      , {i, 1, Length@k}
      ]
  ]


{#, pickAscending[#, Last]} & /@ {t7, t6} // Map[Grid[#] &]



To demonstrate the second argument:
SeedRandom[0];
t8 = Table[{{RandomInteger[{1, 20}], RandomInteger[{1, 20}]}, 
   RandomInteger[{10, 20}]}, 8];

e.g.,
{#, pickAscending[#, First@*First]} &@t8 // 
 Grid[#, Spacings -> {0.3, 0.5}] &


Some outputs with targeted location highlighted:

Original
t7 = {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 11}, {7, 2}, {11, 9}, {13, 19}, {9, 17}};
SequenceCases[t7, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; d < b :> {a, b}]



{{2, 3}, {5, 11}, {13, 19}}


I tried to use your method on t7 = {{{13, 41}, 12}, {{17, 53}, 24}, {{31, 97}, 25}, {{53, 167}, 9}}  with SequenceCases[t7, {{{a_, b_}, c_}, {{d_, e_}, f_}} /; c < f :> {{a, b}, c}] to get the first three elements, but only got the first element. What is my mistake?

Yes, @user57467 is right. Syed's code does not do what is desired. I noticed that when comparing the runtimes of the solutions presented.

Here is another possibility:
FirstCase[t7, {_, #}] & /@ Union@(Max[t7[[;; #, 2]]] & /@ Range[Length[t7]])


FoldPairList allows you to maintain state during iteration. You could use this to keep track of the largest so far.
FoldPairList[
  {If[#2[[2]] > #1[[2]], #2, Missing[]], If[#2[[2]] > #1[[2]], #2, #1]} &, 
  -{Infinity, Infinity}, 
  t7] // DeleteMissing

FoldPairList expects a consistent structure throughout, so we can't just output Nothing in the first If. So I output a token that's easy to remove later. Using -{Infinity, Infinity} as the initial value makes sure we include the first element of t7. You could also roll your own state management in a Select.
Module[
  {s = -Infinity},
  Select[t7, If[#[[2]] > s, s = #[[2]]; True, False] &]]

